# None output, what's the issue?

Tags: python

I have a function that gives me the date in case it's past midnight.

```
def date(hm, date, incr):
    d=get_day(date)
    m=get_month(date)
    y=get_year(date)
    if add_minutes(hm,incr)=='00:00':
        d+=1                                                  
        if (m%2)!=0 and d>31:                                
            m+=1                                             
            rest=d-31                                        
            if m>12:                                         
                m=1
                y+=1
                date=lenght_day_month(d, m, y)
                return date
            else:
                date=lenght_day_month(d, m, y)
                return date
        elif (m%2)!=0 and d<=31:
            date=lenght_day_month(d, m, y)
            return date
        if (m%2)==0 and d>30:
            m+=1
            rest=d-31
            if m>12:
                m=1
                y+=1
                date=lenght_day_month(d, m, y)
                return date
            else:
                date=lenght_day_month(d, m, y)
                return date
        elif (m%2)==0 and d<=30:
            date=lenght_day_month(d, m, y)
            return date
```

Then I execute the same function in an other one like

```
header[1]=str(date(header[3],header[1],5))
print(header[1])
```

And I get as a result `None`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Presumably, the `if add_minutes(hm,incr)=='00:00':` check doesn't pass, and your function terminates without encountering a `return` statement, and thus your function implicitly returns `None`...

Comment: We are missing way too much context to begin helping to debug this. What is `add_minutes()`, for example? What should happen when that function does not return `'00:00'`? Currently, `date()` would return `None` in that case, as well as in other cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an else block for this condition:

```
if add_minutes(hm,incr)=='00:00':
```

Right now, if the time is not midnight, it will return `None` implicitly